# 2つの関数を１つの関数にまとめる書き方を教えてください

Tags: javascript, jquery

`.input_edit` または　`.input_edit_select`をクリックすると編集できる関数を作成したのですが、
別々の関数を作るやり方しかわかりませんでした。

`.input_edit` または　`.input_edit_select`を別々の関数にはせず、
１つの関数の中で`input`も`select`の編集できるようにするにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

教えていただけますと大変助かります。

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input_edit').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
      $(this).addClass('on');
      var txt = $(this).text();
      $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+txt+'" />');
      $('.input_edit > input').focus().blur(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if(inputVal==='') {
          inputVal = this.defaultValue;
        };
        $(this).parent().removeClass('on').text(inputVal);
      });
    };
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.input_edit_select').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
      $(this).addClass('on');
      var txt = $(this).text();
      $(this).html('<select class="form-control"><option selected>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select>');
      $('.input_edit_select > select').focus().blur(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if(inputVal==='') {
          inputVal = this.defaultValue;
        };
        $(this).parent().removeClass('on').text(inputVal);
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>用途</th>
        <th>選択肢</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="input_edit">テスト</td>
        <td class="input_edit_select">A</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

それぞれの関数を見比べると、共通していない部分は

- `html` メソッドの引数
- 指定するセレクタ

の 2 つであることがわかります。

`html` メソッドの引数は色々な要素が入ることを想定し、関数の引数とすることで `input`, `select` 要素のどちらにも対応出来ます。指定するセレクタに関しては、 `.input_edit_select > input`, `.input_edit_select > select` と書かれていますが、これらは次の疑似コード `$(this).children(htmlメソッドで挿入した要素の名前)` と同じ処理をしていると考えることが出来ます。

よって、質問文のコードは以下のように書くことが出来ます。

```
function replace(formControl) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('on')) return;
  var tagName = $(formControl).prop("tagName");
  $(this).addClass('on').html(formControl);
  $(this).children(tagName).focus()
    .blur(function() {
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      if (inputVal === '') inputVal = this.defaultValue;
      $(this).parent().removeClass('on').text(inputVal);
    });
}

$(function() {
  $('.input_edit').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var input = '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + txt + '" />';
    replace.call(this, input);
  });

  $('.input_edit_select').click(function() {
    var select = '<select class="form-control"><option selected>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select>';
    replace.call(this, select);
  });
});
```

```js
function replace(formControl) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('on')) return;
  var tagName = $(formControl).prop("tagName");
  $(this).addClass('on').html(formControl);
  $(this).children(tagName).focus()
    .blur(function() {
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      if (inputVal === '') inputVal = this.defaultValue;
      $(this).parent().removeClass('on').text(inputVal);
    });
}

$(function() {
  $('.input_edit').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var input = '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + txt + '" />';
    replace.call(this, input);
  });

  $('.input_edit_select').click(function() {
    var select = '<select class="form-control"><option selected>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select>';
    replace.call(this, select);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>用途</th>
        <th>選択肢</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="input_edit">テスト</td>
        <td class="input_edit_select">A</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: お教えいただきありがとうございました。大変参考になり、大変勉強になりました。本当にありがとうございます！